# Zero energy eigenstates of the Kitaev chain Hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, superconductivity, eigenvalue, topological-order, majorana-fermions

I am thinking about a two-site Kitaev Hamiltonian. Namely,
$$H = -\mu c^\dagger_1 c_1 -\mu c^\dagger_2 c_2-t c^\dagger_{2} c_1-t c^\dagger_{1} c_2 +\Delta c_1 c_{2}+\Delta c_2^\dagger c_{1}^\dagger.$$

I focus on the topological regime $\mu=0$ and $\Delta=t=1$.

When I switch to a Majorana representation and solve this I end up with two fermionic states which vanish from the Hamiltonian and thus reside at zero energy.

(see 5.3.1 in [these notes](http://topo-houches.pks.mpg.de/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/lecture_Oppen.pdf))

However, if I directly diagonalize the Kitev Hamiltonian (in the basis of $|00\rangle$,$|10\rangle$,$|01\rangle$,$|11\rangle$) I end up having no zero energy eigenstates (see 2.4.2 [here](https://dspace.library.uu.nl/bitstream/handle/1874/365933/Msc%20Thesis%20-%20Georgios%20A.%20Skantzaris.pdf?sequence=2)).

Any unitary transformation should preserve the eigenspectrum which made me conclude that via changing to a "Majorana representation" I must have done something non-unitary to my Hamiltonian?

Is the change from $|00\rangle$,$|10\rangle$,$|01\rangle$,$|11\rangle$ to a Majorana representation non unitary?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing non-unitary going on here: the Hamiltonian matrix and its Majorana fermion representation are entirely equivalent. The confusion here is the mixing up of two distinct concepts: a zero-energy mode (relevant) and a zero-energy state (irrelevant).

A zero-energy *mode* is a mode into which you can add an excitation without changing the energy of the system. So if the mode creation operator is $\hat{a}^\dagger$ and $|0\rangle$ is the ground state with energy $E_0$, then $\hat{a}^\dagger|0\rangle$ is also an energy eigenstate with energy $E_0$, i.e. the ground state is degenerate. The actual value of $E_0$ is completely irrelevant and can be chosen at will by redefining the zero of energy. In particular, there is no requirement that $E_0 = 0$: it does not matter if the energy eigenvalues are zero or not. Instead, the presence of a zero mode is signalled by degeneracies in the spectrum.

Comment: Hi, 

if I understand your answer well you say that Majorana fermions are actually excitations of "ground states" which cost no additional energy. Then the question is how I determine what is a "ground state" or $E_0$ of the Kitaev chain?

Comment: @MarcoR. You already have diagonalised the Hamiltonian right? The ground state is the energy eigenvector with the lowest eigenvalue.